# String to Date conversion for format DD/MM/YYYY in PHP and MYSQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am having problem while inserting the date into the MYSQL database. Consider following variable:

`$mydate = '18/06/2016'` // dd/mm/yyyy format

Now, I am trying to insert this date into the date field(dob) of my MYSQL database which is throwing me syntax error. Following is my PHP/MYSQL query:

```
insert into mytable (dob) values (date('dd/mm/yyyy', strtotime($mydate)))
```

Earlier, when I used to accept date format in mm/dd/yyyy, it was easily getting inserted without any conversion, like this:

```
insert into mytable (dob) values ($mydate)
```

What I am missing here?

**Update:**

My actual query is:

```
insert into users(fullname, dob, notes) values ('Joy', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('15/06/2016')), 'My notes');
```

**Syntax error is:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' strtotime('15/06/2016')), 'My notes')' at line 1
```

Comment: Would you please let me know data type for dob field ?

Comment: @MaulikKanani - I have already mentioned it in my question - "Now, I am trying to insert this date into the 'date' field(dob) of my MYSQL database "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because MySQL accepts `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Try to insert like this,

```
<?php
     $mydate="18/06/2016";
     $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $mydate);
     $dateFormat=$date->format('Y-m-d');
     $sql="INSERT INTO mytable (dob) VALUES ('".$dateFormat."')";
```

Comment: Updated my answer, Please try like this.

Comment: Yes try with my answer and check if that get solved.

Comment: No, using your answer, my final date becomes 1970-01-01.

Comment: What is the value you're getting of `$dateFormat` ?

Comment: When I add date as 08/06/2016, it inserts the date but like this: 2016-08-06. It makes my day as month. I think strtotime by default only takes mm/dd/yyyy format. I am getting the value of $dateFormat = 1970-01-01

Comment: Updated my answer to convert date using `DateTime` object, Please try with that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $date ='18/06/2016';
     $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
     $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
     $dateFormat=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mydate));
     $sql="INSERT INTO mytable (dob) VALUES ('".$dateFormat."')";  
?>
```

Would You please try this one ?